# Perl not printing properly

Tags: perl, function, printing, subroutine

Ok, so I have some sub routines similar to what you see below, my issue is that the print function is not printing out until the actual command is complete, I want it to print
"Has MySQL, Installing:", and then do the command then print OK. I have already tried using sleep and tried clearing the $ssh_d object. Any advice appreciated. Don't worry about the variables in this particular sub, the issue is happening all over. Thanks guys.

```
if ($MySQL)
{
    print "Has MySQL, Installing: ";
    $mysqlCmd = "/path/to/script/mysql-install.pl $person > /dev/null 2>&1";
    $ssh_d->cmd("$mysqlCmd");
    print "OK\n";
}
```

Comment: When you run this without the ssh cmd call (I'm assuming that sshd refers to Net::SSH::Perl), does it print out?  I'm guessing that the cmd call does something to the stdout handle, somehow.

Comment: See "Suffering from Buffering" http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

STDOUT is usually line-buffered, so you won't see your output until you print a newline.  You can set [`$|`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%7C) before printing to force your output to be printed.

To turn on autoflushing after each print, set `$|` to 1:

```
$| = 1;
print "Enter a number between 3 and 5: ";
chomp( my $answer = <STDIN> );
```

(Note that $| isn't actually a single value, it is tracked separately for each filehandle.  When you set it, it affects the setting for the currently selected filehandle (see [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html)).

Comment: Thanks! Can you show me an example of how to use $| I am unfamiliar, this place never fails lol

Comment: @noledgeispower: added an example

Comment: @ysth: Is the autoflush needed here considering that `STDOUT` (in line buffered mode) is flushed automatically when reading from `STDIN`?

Comment: @sid_com: depends.  If stdout is going to a file it can make the output more sane.

Answer (score 5):

> Thanks! Can you show me an example of how to use $| I am unfamiliar, this place never fails lol –

Will this do?

```
$| = 1;
print "This is now unbuffered printing. "
sleep 3;
print "You no longer have to wait for the NL character. ";
sleep 3;
print "\n";
```